# Ember.js - index on nested route duplicating/not destroying on exit

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Having an issue with ember not destroying the index on exit.

Controllers/Routes:

```
App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function () {
        //Doing some stuff with login state here. Not important.
    }
});

App.AccountController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'], //dependency
    account: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.accountData'),
    states: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.states'),
    userToken: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.userToken'),

    tabs: [{'pinned': true, 'name': { 'nestedLink': 'account.index', long: 'Account Overview' }}, {'name': { 'nestedLink': 'account.edit-profile', long: 'Edit Your Company Profile' }}, {'name': { 'nestedLink': 'account.edit-listings', long: 'Edit Your Company Listings' }}, {'name': { 'nestedLink': 'account.edit-payment-methods', long: 'Edit Your Saved Payment Methods' }}, {'name': { 'nestedLink': 'account.view-orders', long: 'View Orders' }}],
});

App.AccountIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['account']
});
```

And here's the router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
        //...
    this.resource('account', function() {
        this.route('edit-profile');
        this.route('edit-listings');
        this.route('edit-payment-methods');
        this.route('view-orders');
    });
});
```

And the account template is set up like the following with the links to each nested route like: `{{#linkTo account.index}}{{/linkTo}}` `{{#linkTo account.view-orders}}{{/linkTo}}`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="account">
            <h2>Account for {{account.name.company}}</h2>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 account-sidebar">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        {{#each tabs}}
                            {{#if pinned}}
                                {{#linkTo name.nestedLink class="list-group-item pinned-item"}}
                                    {{name.long}}
                                {{/linkTo}}
                            {{else}}
                                {{#linkTo name.nestedLink class="list-group-item"}}
                                    {{name.long}}   
                                {{/linkTo}}
                            {{/if}}
                        {{else}}
                            <p class="text-danger">There are no options for your account.</p>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 account-content">
                    {{outlet}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="account/index">
            <h3>Account Overview</h3>
        </script>
```

Switching back and forth between the overview (index) tab and a nested route results in: [image: ember duplication]

Comment: Any chance you could provide a jsFiddle or jsBin?

Comment: @chopper Sigh... Yes.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a bit tough to debug like this

Comment: @chopper Agreed. Fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/novib/1/ Click "Goto Account" and then switch between tabs ("links")

Comment: @chopper Also, just noticed... It's doing more duplication. Seems to be duplicating the entire resource when navigating to another resource. You can replicate this by clicking goto account and then going back in your browsers history....

Comment: @chopper For the sake of being thorough, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/novib/2/ Taking out the index template solves the issue. Am I defining the template wrong or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing `</div>` in your "account/index" template. It should be

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="account/index">
   <h3>Account Overview</h3>
   <hr />
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <h4>Account Created:</h4>
         <p class="text-muted"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <h4>Account Address:</h4>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/novib/3/

Comment: Lmao. Well that was dumb. I didn't even notice it. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry, it happens to the best of us :)